# Problem with command Line argument in Turbo C compiler

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me how i can give command line argument (int argc and char*argv[]) in turbo C compiler??

Thnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Launch a command prompt
- run your executable. if it is abc.exe do : 
  `abc.exe argument1 argument2 argument3 . . . argumentn`

In the code `argv[0]` will contain `abc.exe` , `argv[1]` will contain `argument1` and so on.
`argc` value would be the number of strings in `argv`

Sample

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i=0;
  printf ("\nargc = %d", argc);
  for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
  {
    printf ("\nargv[%d] = %s", i, argv[i]);
  }
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

run with :

`demo.exe hello man this is a test`

Output:

```
argc = 7
argv[0] = demo.exe
argv[1] = hello
argv[2] = man
argv[3] = this
argv[4] = is
argv[5] = a
argv[6] = test
```

P.S.: Please stop using TurboC (3.1)

Comment: Why do you print backwards (`"\nstuff"` versus `"stuff\n"`)? :D

Comment: habit, `"stuff\n"` feels like that there is no soil under the feet of the string. `"\nstuff"` feels like there is a solid base (the `\n`) behind the string protecting it. Its actually mental.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your main's prototype as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and you'll be fine. argc and argv are passed by the operating system (whichever you're using) ;)

Comment: maybe he was a windows fan :)

Comment: @Andrei: ops.. Do they still exist? :P Never mind, will change it =)