# Pass a value while executing c program in terminal

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I have a simple c program `test.c` that increments a variable:

```c
get(var);       //get var when executing test.c
var = var + 1;
printf(%d,var);
```

And i want to set `var` when i execute the program:

> ./test 15

i want to store 15 in `var` in my program and use it.

How can i do that ?

I really tried to search for this but didn't find anything.

Comment: Search for argv and argc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing command-line arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-c)

Comment: The suggested duplicate may be a bit overkill for your question, but I think it has all the information. For a simple argument like one number, there is probably no need for getopt or argp, but these may be convenient to keep in mind.

Comment: Maybe read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981565/clarification-on-argc-and-argv

Comment: Or a complete code example here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Comment: _I really tried to search for this but didn't find anything._  This is homework assignment.  You are not asked to search internet for a solution, you are asked to solve the problem yourself.  Don't search and write valid code (the code you post is incorrect, just will not compile)  You are requested to learn to program, not to learn to search internet for the already made code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the PO is asking for an already made solution to his homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an example to get you started your further searches

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *pname;
    int v;

    if (argc >= 1) {
        pname = argv[0];
        printf("pname = %s\n", pname);
    }

    if (argc >= 2) {
        v = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        printf("v = %d\n", v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Run as:

```
$ ./a.out
pname = ./a.out

$ ./a.out 1234
pname = ./a.out
v = 1234
```

As you may have guessed, the `argc` and `argv` describe the input data passed at execution time.

The `argc` indicates how many arguments were passed to the program. Note that there is ALWAYS at least one argument: the name of the executable.

The `argv` is an array of `char*` pointing to the passed arguments. Thus, when calling `./a.out 1234` you get two pointers:

- argv[0]: `./a.out`.
- argv[1]: `1234`.

Comment: Am using: gcc -Wall -Werror test.c -o test, so it won't even compile. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: is says that variable ‘pname’ set but not used , and for strtol do i have to #include something ?

Comment: @Marwane The code compiles without error on my side. As for `strtol` comes along`stdlib.h`

Comment: @Marwane, good look in your search!!! you are the best! :)